Arduino C++ : how to define lambda function parameter?
I have a function definition that takes a function pointer as an argument:
void ReadLogFile(void (*msgHandler)(String msg) = NULL)
{
  ...
  if (msgHandler) msgHandler(msg);
  ...
}

I try to call this passing a lambda:
logger.ReadLogFile([](String s) 
  {
    MQTT_SendLogEntry(telemetry_topic, s, s);
  });

Turns out that this does not work because telemetry_topic is external to the lambda and it has no access to an external variable. Therefore I change the lambda to capture all external variables:
logger.ReadLogFile([&](String s) 
  {
    MQTT_SendLogEntry(telemetry_topic, s);
  });

This time I get a compilation error:

no suitable conversion function from "lambda [](String s)->void" to "void (*)(String msg)" exists

I can't figure out how to change the declaration of logger.ReadLogFile() to accept such a lambda function, and then how to invoke it from there.

Lambda can be implicitly converted into a function pointer only if it doesn't capture anything.

This depends on MCU and also on the arduino core for that mcu. But in general it's not available on AVR, and it is available on ARM (or Risc-V) - however might not be implemented for Arduino core callbacks or in libraries

A lambda can only be converted to a function pointer if it does not capture, unfortunately (for more, see here.
You can make the parameter a std::function instead, in which case it'd look like this:
void ReadLogFile(std::function<void(String)> msgHandler = nullptr)
{
  ...
  if (msgHandler) msgHandler(msg);
  ...
}

Or, if it's possible, you can make ReadLogFile a template, which also allow it to accept a lambda, in which case it'd look like this
template <typename Func>
void ReadLogFile(Func msgHandler)
{
  ...
  if (msgHandler) msgHandler(msg);
  ...
}


Arduino is a freestanding env and it doesn't have std::function

@bolov well, storing capture would require allocation and that's not embedded-friendly. Time to invent own type erasure or use message pattern

Maybe my wording for Aduino was too loose, as a matter of fact, std::function does compile for platform ESP8266 NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12) and is a doable solution. Thank you.

The easiest way is to make it a template:
template <class Handler>
void ReadLogFile(Handler msgHandler)
{
    msgHandler(msg);
}

This also accepts normal functions (Handler will be deduces as a function pointer).
If you want to handle null pointers you can add an overload for function pointers (like your original function). To not duplicate code you can delegate to the above template after checking for null, but this really depends on your actual code. Here's an example:
template <class Handler>
void ReadLogFile(Handler msgHandler)
{
    msgHandler(msg);
}

void ReadLogFile(void (*msgHandler)(String))
{
    if (msgHandler)
    {
        // delegate to the template overload
        ReadLogFile<void(*)(String)>(msgHandler);

        // this would cause infinite recursion:
        // ReadLogFile(msgHandler);
    }
}


Regarding using std::function. First of all arduino is a freestanding env and it doesn't have std::function. But even if that were an option, due to the type erasure nature of it, std::function (or equivalent) incurs a non-negligible runtime cost (both on creation and on each call).

So std::function does compile for platform ESP8266 NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12), but I understand has increased processing cost, thanks for pointing out. Unfortunately I don't understand the reasoning of "due to the type erasure nature " but its my bad, I am not an experienced C++ coming with a solid C# background.

C++ is strongly typed language. The type std::function erases the type of the object it is assigned and it can do this at runtime. This is what is called type erasure here. In order to be able to do this internally it uses virtual functions and vtables which make the calls to the referenced object indirect calls. Plus it has dynamically allocated memory.

I find it (pleasantly) surprising that std::function is available. What dev environment are you using? Compiler chain and IDE?

I use Arduino IDE for Visual Studio 2022 (also known as vMicro). I strongly suggest using this instead of Arduino IDE due to real Visual Studio experience.
Arduino IDE still required for the compiler, I use version 2.3.0.
